# How to pass object's attribute as prop to vue.js component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-props

Given the following component:

```js
<script>
export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  props: {
    blueprint: {
      type: Object,
      default () {
        return {
          attribute: 0,
          otherAttribute: 5
        }
      }
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      attribute: this.blueprint.attribute,
      otherAttribute: this.blueprint.otherAttribute
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I want to use the `blueprint` prop to populate data fields with some default values which could also be defined when using the component.

But how can I pass only one field of prop `blueprint`?
When I do this:

```html
<my-component :blueprint="{attribute: someVar}" />
```

the `otherAttribute` of the default `blueprint` will be gone, of course.

Can I only set the one field of the prop and merge it with the default of the other, something like this:

```html
<my-component :blueprint.attribute="someVar" />
<!-- It doesn't work like this, but maybe you get the idea what I want -->
```

Sadly the `blueprint` prop has too many fields to pass each field on it's own.

Comment: MyComponent is built by you or it comes from other libraries?

Comment: It is built by me. And I think I found a solution now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah, your Answer is fine. Here is my solution

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  props: {
    blueprint: {
      type: Object
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      blueprintDefault: {
          attribute: 0,
          otherAttribute: 5 
      }
    }
  },
  mounted () {
   this.blueprint = {...this.blueprintDefault, ...this.blueprint}
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that seems to work for me. My component now looks like this:

```js
<script>
export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  props: {
    blueprint: {
      type: Object
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      attribute: this.blueprint.attribute ?? 0,
      otherAttribute: this.blueprint.otherAttribute ?? 5
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I removed the `default` part of the prop and now set the default values directly in the data instead. That way if my `blueprint` prop does not include all attributes, the other default values will still be there.